# Изменение цвета столбца для выделенной ячейки Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Доброе время суток, как изменить цвет столбца выделенной ячейки в datagrid WPF

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Весь столбец выделить?

Comment: Background всего столбца

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так, поместите в ресурсы стиль для выделенной ячейки и подпишитесь на `CurrentCellChanged`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="SelectedColumnStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

В подписчике просто применим стиль к текущему столбцу:

```
DataGridColumn CurrentColumn = null;

private void DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    if (CurrentColumn != null)
        CurrentColumn.CellStyle = null;
    CurrentColumn = dataGrid.CurrentColumn;
    if (CurrentColumn != null)
        CurrentColumn.CellStyle = (Style)dataGrid.Resources["SelectedColumnStyle"];
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]