# Выделить цветом ячейку в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста, как выделить одну ячейку цветом при наведении на неё, по этой ссылке **[Изменение цвета столбца для выделенной ячейки Datagrid WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805729/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-datagrid-wpf)** я нашёл как выделяется полный столбец цветом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения], а нужно вот так сделать [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Заранее благодарю!!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дизайнере щелкните правой кнопкой по DataGrid и в контекстном меню выберите "Edit Additional Templates" - "Edit CellStyle" - "Edit a Copy", выберите куда сохранить стиль. Теперь, в стиль добавьте еще один триггер:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

Не забывайте, что триггеры срабатывают в порядке их определения, поэтому правильно выберите место для него.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!!!